# Number of solution of function on open interval

Tags: calculus

If we have: $f(x)=\frac { 1+x }{ 1+{ e }^{ x } } $

I am told to determine if $f(x)=x$ has multiple roots on $\left[ 0;+\infty  \right] $

I tried to manually solve this equation, but I don't understand the result:

$f(x)-x=0\rightarrow \frac { 1+x }{ 1+{ e }^{ x } } =0\rightarrow { e }^{ x }(x+1)=0$

which would mean that -1 is the only solution. So there shouldn't be any solution on $\left[ 0;+\infty  \right] $.

But when I check on Wolfram, I see that there is a unique solution, and that this solution is 0.56.

Can anybody help please ?

1) How can I find the nb of solutions to this equation ?
2) How can we explain the result I get and the one from wolfram ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=x$, then $f(x)-x=0$, or:
$$\frac{1-xe^x}{1+e^x}=0.\tag{1}$$
Since $1+e^x$ is always positive, $(1)$ is equivalent to:
$$ g(x)=xe^x = 1.\tag{2}$$
$g(x)$ is a decreasing and negative function over $(-\infty,-1)$, an increasing function over $(-1,+\infty)$, since $g'(x) = (x+1)e^x$. So there is at most one real number $x$ such that $xe^x=1$. Exactly one since $xe^x$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$ is positive and unbounded. Such a number is just:
$$ W(1) = 0.567143290409783873\ldots $$
where $W(\cdot)$ is the [Lambert W-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). $W(1)$ can be computed through Newton's method.

Comment: thank you. But, was I supposed to know that the solution was W(1). Or can we manually solve this?

Comment: Once you know that there is only one solution, you can find it numerically through Newton's method.

Comment: How did you find out the variations please ? You did not use any derivative or anything. and how did you find out the -1 ?

Comment: I cannot understand your question. I studied the intervals where $g(x)$ is decreasing/increasing by computing $$\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}xe^x = (x+1)e^x.$$

Comment: Since $e^x>0$, $g'(x)>0$ iff $x>-1$.

Comment: Oh sorry. Excuse me. It was not on your post, so I assumed you did not.

Comment: Check on wolfram, the function is not increasing where you said it was increasing. It is decreasing on R+

Comment: Re-check what you typed on Wolfram. $g'(x)=(x+1)e^x$ gives that $g(x)=xe^x$ *is* increasing on $(-1,+\infty)$.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use this derivative to get the variation of f(x)-x. f(x)-x is decreasing on R+, not increasing. Just looking at the limit shows it is decreasing.

Comment: Dear god, I was talking about $g(x)$.

Comment: -- $g(x)$ is decreasing, $g(x)$ is increasing --

Comment: your $g(x)$ is useful to find out $W(1)$ but it is not useful to find out how $f(x)-x$ behaves on R+.

Comment: $g(x)-1$ and $f(x)-x$ are two different functions, they only share the set of zeroes.

Comment: We agree on that.

Comment: We don't need to know how $f(x)-x$ behaves on $\mathbb{R}^+$. We only need to find its zeroes.

Comment: So, it cannot be used to prove that there is one and only one solution to f(x)-x=0. That's what we are looking for.

Comment: We can accomplish to this task by studying the simpler ausiliary function $g(x)-1$, whose set of zeroes is the same as $f(x)$.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=1$ are equivalent, XCoder.

Comment: Ok, you found it the zeros of f(x)-x via g(x). Allright. But does that is enough to determine that we have ONLY ONE solution ?

Comment: If the solutions of $f(x)-x=0$ and $g(x)=1$ are the same, and $g(x)=1$ has only one solution...

Comment: ok. Thanks. Just to precise, this was an exam question. And I was not aware of W(1). I don't know how I could have known that g(x) had only one solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help and support Jack. Regards,

Comment: @XCoder, Jack D'Aurizio's solutions has two parts. One that proves there's exactly one solution. And another (bonus part) that identifies the solution as W(1). So you didn't need to know about the W function.

Comment: Oh ok. But one stupid question: by looking at the function g(x), it was not obvious to me that this thing has a solution and only one.

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous increasing function over $I$ and $y\in f(I)$, there is only one $x\in I$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x) - x = \frac{1+x}{1+e^x} - x = \frac{1+x}{1+e^x} - \frac{x(1+e^x)}{1+e^x} = \frac{1-xe^x}{1+e^x}$$